# aggregate test reports with JGiven

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, jgiven

I have a multi-module Java 21 /Spring Boot 3 / Maven project, and I use JGiven for my tests.

I want to aggregate the reports from my sub-modules into a single HTML.

How can I do this?

Thanks.